# Hiding text fields or buttons on a form by row rather than the whole form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am stuck with a problem.
I have an Access database form with 3 text boxes in a row and I want to show or hide them based on if another field shows a `1`, `2` or `3` or none if `0`.

Currently I have them side by side and it looks a bit rubbish and would like them on.

The 3 fields are `text1`, `text2` and `text3`.
The field it is looking at is `completed`.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Aaron

Comment: *and would like them on .* What? -- In continuous forms, you can only use **Conditional Formatting** for this.

Comment: I did but cannot see how to hide only to enable or disable.

Comment: Tried with If me.completed = 1 then me.text3.visible = true but this didn't work.  It changes it for all rows not just the ones with the correct criteria.

Comment: Sorry Andre.  I would kind of like them on top of each other and only show when the criteria is correct.  Can this be done with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You can't toggle visiblity with Conditional Formatting.

But you can simply use a single text box, and set its **back color** with Conditional Formatting:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129

You can set the text dynamically in the underlying query, with `IIf()` or `Switch()`